# Heroku Django app deployment fails after trying to install python requirement

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I installed django-user-visit with  `pip install django-user-visit` , tested it in my local environment and everything seems to work fine, but when i try to deploy my app to production with **Heroku** i get the following error :

```
remote:        Collecting django-cors-headers==3.6.0
remote:          Downloading django_cors_headers-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-user-visit==0.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_940d12d0/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: _No matching distribution_ found for django-user-visit==0.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_940d12d0/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Does anyone know why Heroku can't find the package and if i can fix this ?

My packages are being installed by running the libraries indicated in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.5
django-cors-headers==3.6.0
django-user-visit==0.4.1
djangorestframework==3.12.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.4.1
ua-parser==0.10.0
user-agents==2.2.0
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

What i've tried so far is to change the version to 0.4 and to not specify a version at all

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Do you have a `runtime.txt`?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-user-visit/ requires Python >= 3.7. You need to use Python 3.7+ at Heroku.

Comment: Thank you Chris and phd, i guess that is my problem, Heroku is running 3.6.12 while my localhost 3.9, i will specify version 3.7 in my runtime.txt file

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes

If you’re running a Python application that requires a different supported runtime, or if you simply want to lock your project against patch updates until you’re ready to upgrade, you can specify which runtime to use for your app.

To specify a Python runtime, add a `runtime.txt` file to your app’s root directory that declares the exact version number to use.

after that

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```